# Вопрос парсинга json на php

Tags: json, php

Здравствуйте, возникла проблема
json конфиг имеет данное строение
[Ссылка](https://api.worldoftanks.ru/wot/clan/info/?application_id=demo&clan_id=4835)

Вывожу так, к примеру

```
echo $jsoninfo->data->$clanid->description_html . '<br>'; // Описание
```

но возникла проблема, что дальше есть пользователи, то есть members
каждый пользователь имеет свой ид
вопрос в этом как получить у всех их иды и роль в клане

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach($obj->data->members as $id => $val) {
    echo "id: " . $id . ", Роль: " . $val->role_i18n;
}
```